# Shunt regulation - discrete or linear?

Tags: voltage-regulator, shunt, braking, regenerative

This is a spin-off of the [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/681211/187920) I've asked before. I've received many interesting answers and summarized them there. I also accepted most interesting suggestion. During this time we also bought and tested two commercial devices, [EM-A43](https://electromen.com/en/products/item/supportive-products/electronics/EM-A43) and [LUGE-SR060](https://www.e-motionsupply.com/LUGE_Shunt_Regulator_LUGE_SR060_080_p/luge-sr060-080.htm) with [external resistor](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/vishay-sfernice/LPS0600H2R00JB/17139311). They work as expected but are expensive and have inconvenient (in our particular case, not in general) form factor.

So, I'd like to proceed with developing of our own device, and for this I need some help. I've selected two options from earlier discussion: comparator with MOSFET/IGBT and linear regulator with BJT.
[image]

It is my understanding that the first circuit will work by rapid on/off switching, potentially creating a lot of noise. Also powering the comparator and gate driver from the very voltage being controlled might be problematic. On a plus side, the bulk of the dissipation will be on a resistor, with only switching losses on the FET.

The second circuit will control resistor current, keeping the voltage mostly constant. However selection of the resistor will be crucial, and the power dissipated on the transistor can be very high. I am planning on using [MJH6284G](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/onsemi/MJH6284G/919546) with [HS300-1R8-J](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/ARCOL-Ohmite/HS300-1R8-J?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlubZbdhIBIEgN9MQql2m6CH9pxz4wnCM%3D) or [CJP400J1R8J](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/TE-Connectivity-Holsworthy/CJP400J1R8J?qs=sGAEpiMZZMtlubZbdhIBIFITUtFUppA2wZU4B3%2FqxnI%3D).

I did preliminary calculations and stumbled upon an interesting phenomena. Let's say the circuit is designed to dissipate 450W. With 1.8R resistor it will dissipate 400W, the remaining 50W will be on transistor. However if the brakes applied gradually, the total power and current drop linearly, while the dissipation on the resistor drops squarely (due to 2 in I<sup>2</sup>R). For example 300W will be split 180/120 between resistor and transistor. This makes me worry of the second solution.

**Requirements:**

Total weight 230kg braking from 10km/h to full stop in 2s => 890J, 450W.
 Voltage threshold 30V.

**Questions:**

- Which circuit configuration is beter?
- Are my calculations for power distribution between resistor and transistor correct?
- How to power both circuits, considering the voltage fluctuations generated by circuits themselves?
- Does the second circuit need biasing or bipolar supply and how can I implement it?

*Clarifications:*

The title refers to the control signal going into power stage. It is discrete on/off in case of comparator and linear when coming from differential amplifier.

It is important to notice that this circuit will only activate when the battery is fully charged AND the braking is hard or long. It can activate while driving down slope or hard braking right after disconnecting the charger, which may be *never* for any particular user. In all other cases the regen will simply be absorbed by the battery.

**UPDATE**

We have received additional info on the inner workings of the motor controller from the manufacturer. It turns out @MathKeepsMeBusy was spot on re charging pump involved in regen:

> During regen the motor together with the associated bridge components
> create a boost converter. Since the motor has an inductance and
> together with the high and low-side FETs it becomes a boost converter
> SMPS, where turning on the low-side FET (high-side off) will cause the
> inductor in the motor to charge up and then turning on the high-side
> FET (low-side is off) the converter enters flyback mode and the
> current flows into the battery rail.

This does not change the question in any way, I just wanted to mention this interesting mechanism that turned my understanding of the process upside down.

Comment: Please explain what the voltage is that you wish to clamp and what series source impedance it has. Also mention what hold-up capacitance there is on the terminals marked \$\Phi\$. Both circuits are lacking values which, in my opinion means they are not really schematics in what I believe to be the true sense. Calculations might be useful but, simulations will always win the day in my opinion. Both circuits are linear and both look likely to be discrete.

Comment: @Andyaka They are not actual schematics, they are concept drawings. The schematic is what I hope to end up with as a result of the feedback. The voltage threshold is 30V. I have no idea how to measure source impedance or capacitance. If you have suggestions I am all ears. Both are the complex combinations of battery, wiring, motors, bulk capacitors in motor driver, and quite a few additional electrical modules.

Comment: @Maple you need to find out what the source impedance is (and bulk capacitance) or you have no way to calculate peak powers based on only knowing the full energy needed to be burnt. Your main question was which schematic is better (just saying).

Comment: @Andyaka May I point out that manufacturers of the commercial regulators have no way of knowing this information, nor they include any limitations in datasheets. I've linked two of them in the beginning and two more in the original question. This leads me to believe that simple shunt regulator can be made to operate in wide range of the operating conditions. After all, its only purpose is to burn out excess power and keep voltage under threshold. Does it really matter where that power came from or how it was influenced by system inductance/capacitance?

Comment: As I implied in my last comment, it's the peak power (the very short duration pulses of power that you might inadvertently take if you don't have a more complete picture of the full system) that is a certain MOSFET/BJT destroyer. And, it does totally depend on things you are unable to currently define. So, on that basis alone you have to use MOSFET on/off hysteresis and resistor power dissipation. That doesn't appear to be an option you have listed because both your circuits are linear in operation.

Comment: @Andyaka I understand. Those are the reasons I've selected transistor with 100V and 40A peak current, as well as resistor with pulse capability 10x times rated power. I think   making rugged device with a lot of reserve is the best I can do to address these concerns

Comment: But, you cannot use a linear circuit because that will burn the MOSFET in milliseconds. It has to be on/off with hysteresis acting like an oscillator until the voltage drops below the  unsafe area.

Comment: @Andyaka umm... that is why the first circuit uses _comparator_ with MOSFET. And the second uses differential amplifier with BJT. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @Andyaka Also I thought there will be gate driver between the comparator and the FET in the final circuit. The comparator will provide hysteresis, while gate driver will minimize switching time.

Comment: A typical comparator doesn't provide hysteresis naturally and, those that do (a much rarer breed) apply a limited amount of hysteresis that would not be sufficient for your application. In other words, both circuits shown in your question **are** linear circuits.

Comment: @Andyaka hence my appeal to the knowledge of people like yourself in helping me design the actual schematic. As for linear vs discrete, please, see a clarification I've added to the question. Maybe "analog" would be better term than "linear". But I think we are focusing on the wrong question here. I've presented two options and asked for help to choose and evolve one of them. If you feel like neither is good then you can add your option to the original question and I'll be glad to consider it.

Comment: @Maple  I can reopen this question but ** ONLY IF** suitable changes are made. I had nothing to do with the question being closed, but, alas, it was predictable. In your last question you did not define the problem clearly in the question proper and did not take my advice re doing so. || In this question the problem is also not at all clear and you refer people back to the original unclear question. ||

Comment: I have a reasonable idea of what you want, and I could build a device that did what you want BUT my job here is to help and/or to encourage people to provide good questions and good answers. I am not able (especially at the moment) to spend substantial time rewriting questions (or answers) - the more so when people are able to do so themselves. Step back and look at your question. if you had no idea of what you wanted would ither question tell you what was wanted? (Others can't)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon You can delete this. I don't see how more "focused" I can make it. All I did is presented two options and asked help in choosing better one. __I know exactly what functionality I want, and I expressed it clearly.__ I also linked to 4 commercial devices that perform this function without asking "how would you use it". __This proves that requirements I've specified are sufficient to design such a device.__ I have no doubt that there are more people like you who know how to build this. I am sorry that they've chosen not to.

Comment: What is ironic though, is that there are already [other questions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/682121/187920) being closed as duplicates and linked to mine "unfocused" ones as having answers. This issue is real and it has simple solutions, but people won't find them here.

Comment: @Maple  DO NOT get annoyed by this. Your solutions are available here. Giving in is not in your interest. I assure you (and you can choose to believe me or not) that I am the "Good Cop" here. I have tried hard (and continue to do so) to help you to help yourself, as you are able to do. You have several times complained about the system not working your way. You are correct. It doesn't. ut it works well enough and you need to work with it. The close vote system reasons are poor - we can't change them. The real enough close reasons are found in the many comments made (and that there ...

Comment: ... are  enthusiastic "close voters" who (genuinely)_ see it's their civic duty to keep the site pure. They are following the rules. AGAIN - DO NOT GET ANNOYED. PLEASE LISTEN TO WHAT I AM SAYING. You for whatever reason have consistently failed to put all the information clearly "up front" in the question(s). || The other closed question has been referred to your question with TWELVE answers and they will find a solution there if they read through it all BUT you do not find it strange that twelve answers are somehow all wrong. IF they are, then having a clearer question may help.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "You for whatever reason have consistently failed to put all the information clearly "up front" in the question(s)" I hear what you are saying, but I don't understand it. What information _exactly_ did I not provide? I described the problem, I provided use case (and other people provided more of these), and I gave all the technical requirements necessary. I even provided links to commercial products that perform this function _without_ any technical requirements given in advance. And I did not say that 12 answers are all wrong, quite the opposite.

Comment: ... I've selected two most promising of them and asked for help choosing one. I also did preliminary calculations and listed my concerns. It is possible that I do not understand how analog circuits work, but that's why I came here. If you think I am wasting your time you are welcome to delete this. If you think you can make the question better you are more than welcome to edit it, because I don't understand what is it that expected of me.

Comment: ...This issue even has little to do with lithium batteries. The shunt regulators (aka dynamic braking resistors) are routinely used with WFD and AC in high power industrial applications. The proliferation of lithium batteries in DC applications only exacerbated it. The manufacturers like [Roboteq](https://www.roboteq.com/applications/all-blogs/36-protecting-against-reneration) are making a killing without asking how or why. "you have regen drive and lithium battery? you need our device! That would be $500, thank you". All I wanted is make our own, preferably cheaper and smaller.

Comment: I'll try to spend some time on this in the next few days, Very busy at present (or should be :-). the LiIon battery appears pivotal. Lead Acid  will still absorb current when about fully charged and BMS (if even equipped) does not prevent this. LiIon must not so allow over-voltage so BMS shuts it off so rail spikes and controller shuts down and puts brakes on and ...  || As answers have said - energy can be absorbed as a spike (as commercial unit quoted doe - with 200W long term sinking) OR by keeping batteries below full so they have some spike absorb capacity. || ...

Comment: @Maple I did not vote to close this question, but I also did not engage with it either (until now). The reason is that I don't believe you understand your system well enough, and you are likely to be quite disappointed if/when you ultimately implement your resistive braking solution. As you it, companies are eager to sell you their resistive brakes. What you may not realize is their own sales people may not fully understand when their system is appropriate. Both of the links to products in your question refer to regenerative braking as _increasing_ voltage to your battery...

Comment: @Maple ...but as I tried to explain in your other question, braking does not increase the emf. You get the same emf coasting at the same speed. What I believe is likely the case is that whenever your wheelchair is going fast enough, the voltage rises to a point where it starts feeding back into the battery.  This isn't the effect of braking, rather the regenerative braking is the _result_ of the rotor speed and voltage going above a certain point. Thus, the claim by vendor about why regen braking cannot be turned of is misleading. It isn't because users demand it for distance...

Comment: @maple ...it's because the circuit doesn't support turning off regen braking ever. It isn't designed with that capability. Rather than admit inadequate design to support Li-ion batteries, they blame customer demand. What needs to be done is to prevent excess voltage when battery is full. This can be prevented by preventing top speed operation at full battery. Even slightly below top speed would solve proble. This may be implementable without an expensive resistive brake, because you already have plug braking available. It certainly could be done if the controller were designed for it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I appreciate your attention to this. "whenever your wheelchair is going fast enough, the voltage rises to a point where it starts feeding back into the battery" I have never seen this in practice. We spent hours testing the chair and logging voltage and current. The faster you go the more current drain on the battery and the more battery voltage drops. It recovers a bit after you stop. Only when you start braking or drive downhill the voltage jumps up. Normally it is absorbed by the battery, never rising more than 2-3V above battery voltage at full stop.

Comment: However when the battery is fully charged (29.4V) the braking voltage gets above 31V limit set in BMS, at which point BMS disconnects charge FET, causing the bus voltage jump above 42V limit of the motor driver. The driver shuts down, the parking brakes engage and the chair violently stops.

Comment: You can start driving at _full speed_ (10kmh) right off the charger, when the battery voltage is at maximum. No problem whatsoever. If you manage to drive for about 15 minutes without slowing down then you will never see this over-voltage disconnect, because the battery will have enough buffer capacity to absorb even very sharp braking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148952/discussion-between-math-keeps-me-busy-and-maple).

Comment: @Maple  0100 in NZ. Maybe later "today". More likely Mon-Tue NZT. Will happen.

Answer (score 1):

A shunt regulator, whether digital or linear, works by dissipating power at the **source**, as much as in the series resistor. If the power supply is relatively "stiff", i.e., has a low source impedance, the shunt may burn out the power supply before voltage falls within the desired range.

A digital shunt regulator pulses the load, so that a series inductor could be inserted increase the source impedance and efficiency. A [linear shunt regulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regulator) might find a use in some applications such as photovoltaic power, where input current is limited, or in very low-power circuits, where the waste is negligible.

So the big question is how this type of regulator will be used, and why you've chosen shunt regulation at all.

Comment: "So the big question is how this type of regulator will be used, and why you've chosen shunt regulation at all." The answers to these questions can be found in the [original question here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/681211/187920)

Comment: "If the power supply is relatively "stiff", i.e., has a low source impedance, the shunt may burn out the power supply before voltage falls within the desired range." Sorry, I am not good at analog circuits. Would not low source impedance mean that most of the power will be dissipated on a resistor, not on power supply?

Comment: A resistor energy absorber could cost far less than the commercial units. Nichrome wire can be used to make  200W - 500W range air scpaced air cooled resistor. Or even many smaller ceramic air cooled are "cheap enough". Switch is not hard. Logic takes some design.

Answer (score 0):

Either can work.   The switching implementation puts the energy in the R which is easier to specify and more rugged. But you have to tune and verify the switching behavior.

The linear approach requires an expensive transistor for the reasons you identified.  And don’t just look at the front page of the data sheet.  Check the thermals and the safe operating area curves - both fets and bjt’s have breakdown modes in their linear region.l characterized in the SOA curves.  And note you can’t parallel fets in the linear region - you have to buy a big expensive one.

To power the circuit I think it’s wise to power from the rail being clamped and there is no problem with this.  Use a linear regulator or a small shunt regulator with a zener.

Note there is an even simpler topology for the linear solution.   You can insert an R in this topology if you want and it can work with either BJT or fet (BJT has less Vbe variation but will burden the Zener with high current making it harder to specify).

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8PuI.png

Comment: Thank you for addressing the actual questions. It is good to know that it can be powered from actual rails being clamped with a simple linear regulator. The circuit you've suggested is a variant of [Jasen's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/681215/187920) to the old question. The reason I've decided against it is that fine tuning it seems to be harder than simply adding variable pot to one input of a comparator/linear amplifier.