# How to use PSRR specification?

Tags: voltage-regulator, shunt, psrr

While working on the shunt regulator previously discussed [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/681211/187920), I've found some high-voltage components that may reduce circuit complexity a lot, since they can be powered directly from bus voltage. However since the circuit itself will be chopping the bus voltage I am not sure if this is a good idea.

My understanding is that I have to look at PSRR specification to see how much the output of each component will be affected and then somehow combine these for the whole chain. But lack of theoretical knowledge leaves me totally confused. Here is the circuit I have in mind:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2filguE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The components:
Voltage reference [MAX6043](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/max6043.pdf)
Comparator [TLV1811](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlv1811.pdf)
Gate Driver [ZXGD3003E6](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ZXGD3003E6.pdf)

Is this a workable solution?

Also, I would appreciate if anybody can tell me if I should add gate resistor or deal with Miller effect somehow (as shown in ZXGD3003E6 datasheet for example)? I always thought that the whole point of gate drivers was to overcome any capacitance effects on the gates.

Comment: I have used comparators before to drive small-medium size MOSFETs directly in a chopping shunt. This works, but due to the large open-loop output impedance of IC comparators, you leave the gate a little "dangling in the wind" when fast transients occur, which can be an issue. I second @TimWilliams that the switch drive should be a bit more rugged. I would indeed suggest an actual low side driver with e.g. 4A source/sink into a proper MOSFET. Don't mind the low supply voltage limit: You just need a single TL431 or even Zener diode to make a suitable rail for your chopper and comparators.

Comment: @tobalt I take it you do not consider ZXGD3003 "an actual low side driver". My alternative choice was [IXD_609](https://www.littelfuse.com/media?resourcetype=datasheets&itemid=63dc5a9e-6cea-4349-bf4e-4540dadb0b53&filename=ixd-609). My initial schematic had 5V comparator powered by basic NPN + zener source. Then I found these 40V chips and thought I can reduce the number of components by half

Comment: @tobalt I understand what you and Tim Williams are saying about MOSFET. But would not IGBT have much lower EMI? We do have to pass FDA.

Comment: Ah, sorry. No I would consider it a gate driver :) I didn' relaize you were going with one, because the schematic said TLV1812 (a comparator).

Comment: an IGBT is mainly *slower*, but you can also make a MOSFET slow using a gate resistor. It really depends on the currents. In your schematic it looks like your current is up to 12 Amps, so IMO, this is clearly MOSFET territory, especially at 24 V. If you want it slow, then also a 5 A gate driver is overkill and you could likely indeed drive the chopper transistor directly from the comparator.

Comment: @tobalt Oops.. that is actually my fault, I put a wrong part number on schematics. Fixed now. The maximum current is 15A at the 30V threshold voltage, calculated to satisfy the requirement to dissipate 450W braking power for 2 seconds.

Comment: I wouldn't think PSRR is particularly relevant if you're chopping your power supply.  That spec refers to a chip that's ON, not a chip that you're turning on and off.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I suspect I did not explain the setup properly. The chips are supposed to be always on, powered directly from the bus. If the bus voltage exceeds the threshold these chips will activate shunt to bring it down. But not all the way down, of course, only to the lover hysteresis threshold. My concern is that fluctuating supply voltage will affect the outputs of these chips to the point where they will miss the thresholds or begin self-sustaining oscillation

Comment: I've realized that the question as stated falls into "lacks focus" category. So, I've removed side question and re-formulated the primary from generic "will this work" to more specific "how to do this".

Comment: Rolling back edit as it invalidates existing answers -- see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286803/change-to-question-invalidates-my-answer-what-to-do/286804#286804

Comment: @TimWilliams "invalidates existing answers". it invalidated one answer out of two. The rollback actually invalidated the other one. Oh, well.. Now you can mark it for closure and call it a day.

Comment: Answer(s) inclusive, that is. I don't see any particular need to close this, and out of currently 69 views it seems no one else has yet. I do appreciate the added detail; a full rollback is a rather blunt instrument here.  Also, existing answers do not limit others from contributing about other aspects of your question. If such responses aren't forthcoming, you may want to ask a new, narrower question; simply explaining PSRR with a worked example, and applying it to the case of a noisy supply, would seem to do here.

Answer (score 3):

The PSRR will mostly affect your reference. That means that the shunt regulator voltage might be slightly off from where you'd expect it.

The comparator will hardly be affected as it makes a differential measurement and saturates its output either way.

A very efficient fix would be to add RC lowpass filters between the chopped rail and the supply pins of the reference and the comparator. This will still cause the low frequency supply voltage seen by these ICs to change, but it will keep the chopping ripple away from its supply. This is helpful, because low frequency PSRR is usually much greater than at higher frequency.

Nevertheless, I would agree with Scott Seidmann and others, in that any worry about PSRR is not really warranted here. The tolerance of your divider resistors for instance is probably a far greater source of error and even this is completely acceptable for a basic overvoltage limiter, which anyway should have plenty of margin left.

Comment: Interesting idea on RC lowpass. But wouldn't it create a delay on power line relative to inputs, which is prohibited by datasheet (max IN is (V+) + 0.3V)?

Comment: also, why RC and nor LC? I usually use RC for signals and LC for power

Comment: @maple if you look at all pins, you'd realize that none of them will be close to Vin. RC is just to prevents oscillations. Also for HF blocking, RC or bead-C is better than L-C because inductors have the most parallel capacitance

Comment: "The comparator will hardly be affected as it makes a differential measurement" When I started calculating resistors setting hysteresis, I've realized that the above is only true without them. The equation (5) in datasheet shows that Voff depends on Vcc, which in this case is Vbus. Trying to set Vbus threshold using Vbus itself seems like a __very__ bad idea. Looks like this circuit is not going to work after all. I can try powering comparator from voltage reference though. Its quiescent is only 5uA and output is 10 mA, same as maximum source from the reference

Comment: @Maple the voltage when the shunt switches on (i.e. the limiting voltage) will not depend on supply voltage, because in this state the comparator output is zero. The supply should only affect the voltage at which the shunt turns off again.

Comment: Yes, that's what equation (5) says. So, when the shunt switches on, say at 31V, the voltage begins to drop. So the threshold for the switch to turn off also moves with it. It could be 29V at Vcc 31V, but as Vcc drops to 30.5 the threshold may change to 29.5 and so on

Comment: No, the threshold changes only slightly @Maple, according to the division ratio of the triangular divider set up by R1 R2 R4.

Comment: Hmm... that is not how I understand equation (5). According to it the OFF threshold depends on R4, R5 and Vcc. I think the Vcc comes into picture because R5 loop connects to the output, and the output is Vcc-0.25, i.e. it changes when Vcc drops. That's what Figure 9-6 shows too

Answer (score 2):

Would a simpler solution not be acceptable?  I made this some time ago for example:

Project build log: [24V Load Ballast | EEVblog Forum](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/projects/24v-load-ballast/)

Schematic:

[image]

Source: my site, https://www.seventransistorlabs.com/Images/ShuntBallast.pdf

The hysteresis band (set by R7 into R4 || R8) may be subject to change depending on what kind of batteries you have (like, alas, my lead acid are pretty toast by now anyways, I don't really care that the peak voltage is rather high as shown), or what exact supply network you have, for example if there's a switch between battery and inverter bus so the voltage can rise arbitrarily (when overcharging would otherwise occur), making the shunt's job much much easier.

Idle current isn't particularly good (mainly because of the 9V zener, and the TL431's minimum Ik sunk by R2), but that could be optimized easily enough.

Gate drive is quite mediocre, as a combination of the extremely low Qgd of the TI NEXFETs used, and on account of not needing (or wanting) to be very fast as the maximum switching frequency is some kHz (determined by hysteresis and bus capacitance).  IGBTs are a terrible choice at 24V, but if you don't mind heatsinking them I suppose that's still fine.

Whether the switching noise / hysteresis bothers anything else in the system, is another matter.  In my case, the charger / testing source (equivalent to a regenerative drive for present purposes) is fine with supply within nominal bounds, regardless of ripple.  Whether it's a problem for your system, only you can know.

Comment: This seems to be functionally similar to the proposed schematic, only using 3 times more components. The devil as always is in the details. Here are some: we do have a switch, but in normal operation it will be closed most of the time, so idle current is important. With components shown I estimated it around 330uA. The idea behind IGBT  was to use their "softer" switching behavior to reduce noise and get rid of those bulk capacitors in your schematics. With built-in capacitors in the motor drivers we are already getting close to inrush problem of BMS shutting down when main switch is closed

Comment: Dealing with that inrush current would require additional components introduced into the system that we just got rid of. The missing pieces on the schematics in the question are 2 resistors to set comparator hysteresis. I have no idea how to estimate chopping frequency/ripple/noise, so I was going to get those experimentally after the board is assembled. Re overshot mentioned in your blog, we are using non-inductive LPS0600H2R00JB resistor.

Comment: The difference is that it's engineered, tested, functional and proven. The purpose of the capacitors is not switching transients but setting the maximum switching frequency. Inrush is a separate problem, with its own solutions, independent of whatever a braking resistor system might require.

Comment: I appreciate your help and we will certainly take a closer look at your schematic, but this does not actually answer either of the two questions, i.e how to use PSRR data from the linked datasheets to find out if the activated shunt regulator will affect the function of its own components, and whether or not gate driver can be connected directly to the switch

Comment: "The purpose of the capacitors is ... setting the maximum switching frequency" Wouldn't it be set by hysteresis? Not as effective as capacitor, I admit, and if set too long may cause extra drain on the battery. But I am trying to reduce the number of components and squeeze the whole thing into somewhat limited space.

Comment: There are three questions actually; I was answering the middle one "*Is this a workable solution?*" by way of offering an alternative. This is instead of spending my time reviewing an incomplete schematic, which is more likely to result in ongoing conversation, which is discouraged on this site, and soak up valuable time that I could be spending on other things.

Comment: I understand. I've added hysteresis resistors and bypass cap required for TLV1821 to the schematic. Now it is complete, save for some resistor values. The divider resistors depend on the available MAX6043 part (planning on using 10V reference). The initial hysteresis I am going for is 29.8V(off)~30.2V (on).